# Run downloaded install4j update without scheduling

Tags: install4j

Is there any other way than using the "Schedule update installation" action and `UpdateChecker.executeScheduledUpdate` to run a downloaded update?

Specifically I want to avoid the 24 hours before retrying after a failed installation attempt of the default scheduling (I want it rescheduled immediately).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the system property

```
-Dinstall4j.updateRetryInhibition=nnnn
```

that specifies the inhibition time in minutes.

Comment: That worked like a charm! Thanks for quick answer. Do you know if this is documented anywhere? I counldn't find it.

Comment: It actually is not. I will add it to the documentation.